# Qt c2664 compiler error in ui setup

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I am using Qt 5.7.1 (5.8) and when I try to compile my project, I get an error:

> Error: C2664: "void Ui_OverviewHistogram::setupUi(QFrame *)" :
>   Converting from argument 1 of "OverviewHistogram *const " to "QFrame
>   *" not possible

(translated from german)
and I have no idea why... The strange thing is, that a lot of seamingly similar classes compile without any issue, just this one will not work. I tried to change the ui to a pointer, but it did not work.

The `ui_overviewhistogram` component of this class is a simple QFrame object designed completely in the Qt designer without any outside manual code 'hacking'.

I am relatively new to C++ and Qt and I can't figure out a solution (not even why this is a problem), can anyone help me with it?

---

My code:

overviewhistogram.h

```
#ifndef OVERVIEWHISTOGRAM_H
#define OVERVIEWHISTOGRAM_H

#include <QFrame>
#include <QColormap>
#include "AnalysisSession.h"
#include "ui_overviewhistogram.h"

namespace Ui {
class OverviewHistogram;
}

class OverviewHistogram : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    OverviewHistogram(Examination *examination, double max = 400, int w = 175, QWidget *parent = 0);
...
}
#endif // OVERVIEWHISTOGRAM_H
```

overviewhistogram.cpp

```
OverviewHistogram::OverviewHistogram(Examination *examination, double max, int w, QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
...
}
```

Comment: The `#include "ui_overviewhistogram.h"` is supposed to go into the `.cpp` file, not the `.h`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I changed that, but it still doesn't work... (does it really make a difference where I include it?)